# How to adjust @timestamp to local time zone in Elastalert

Tags: elastalert

i'm trying to adjust returned datetime value proper for my time zone. My notifications looks like this:

```
An abnormally low number of events occurred around 2016-09-28 22:49 CEST.
```

And this is proper date refered to my time zone.
In field's section in notification I'm getting time for UTC-0 zone:

```
@timestamp: 2016-09-28T20:49:44.711696Z
```

I have tried to use Enhancement this way,
file in `..\elastalert\elastalert_modules`

```
from datetime import datetime
from elastalert.enhancements import BaseEnhancement

class TimeEnhancement(BaseEnhancement):
    def process(self, match):
        if '@timestamp' in match:
            now = datetime.now()
            hours2 = datetime(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0)
            match['@timestamp'] = now + hours2
```

I also add usage in rule:

```
match_enhancements:
- "elastalert_modules.my_enhancements.TimeEnhancement"
```

It's just for test, not for ultimate solution

Comment: I tried to write a alternative solution that does not hardcode the field names but i haven't been able to get it to work.. if i do ill update my issue at github. https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/861

Answer (score 1):

With some help on github i managed to get something that works (i think it formats the datetimes to the same timezone that the server is running)
Python2:

```
from elastalert.util import pretty_ts
from elastalert.enhancements import BaseEnhancement


class TimeEnhancement(BaseEnhancement):
    def process(self, match):
        for k, v in match.items():
            if isinstance(v, basestring) and v.endswith('Z'):
                try:
                    match[k] = pretty_ts(v)
                except:
                    pass
```

Python3:

```
from elastalert.util import pretty_ts
from elastalert.enhancements import BaseEnhancement


class TimeEnhancement(BaseEnhancement):
    def process(self, match):
        for k, v in match.items():
            if isinstance(v, str) and v.endswith('Z'):
                try:
                    match[k] = pretty_ts(v)
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: For Python3+, replace `basestring` with `str`.

Comment: @Dennis tnx made the needed changes

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to @Peter as I only needed a field with localtime.

```py
from elastalert.util import pretty_ts
from elastalert.enhancements import BaseEnhancement


class TimeEnhancement(BaseEnhancement):
    '''
    Add local @timestamp (server time)
    '''

    def process(self, match):
        if '@timestamp' in match:
            ts = match['@timestamp']
            if isinstance(ts, str) and ts.endswith('Z'):
                match['@timestamp_local'] = pretty_ts(ts)
```